# Convergence of localic maps

Tags: limits-and-convergence, locales

We can define a limit of a sequence of points in a locale in the usual way: $x$ is a limit of $\{ x_i \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ if, for every open $U$ containing $x$, there exists $N$ such that $x_n$ belongs to $U$ for every $n > N$. Now, let's say that we have a sequence of localic maps $\{ f_i : X \to Y \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. Can we define a limit of such a sequence? For topological spaces, we can use pointwise convergence. Of course, we can do the same thing for locales, but it seems less natural and I don't think we can do much with such a definition.

If $X$ is exponential, then we can consider $f_i$ as points in the locale $Y^X$, so we can apply the definition that I gave before. The problem here is that the definition of $Y^X$ is rather complicated and I'm not sure how to prove anything about such a notion of convergence (like uniqueness) or how to prove that any given specific sequence of maps converges to something. So, is this definition a reasonable one or is there some other definition of convergence for localic maps? It's OK to assume that $X$ and $Y$ satisfy some properties like Hausdorffness or metrizability.

Comment: Pointwise convergence is usually not very useful in topology, because pointwise limits of sequences of continuous maps often fail to be continuous. Usually one needs something more restrictive like uniform convergence, uniform convergence on bounded subsets, compact-open convergence etc. There are numerous generalizations of these notions of convergence, some of which even leave the realm of topological spaces. I have no idea if any of that also applies to locales, but that's probably the direction one should look in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pretty good notion of convergence of maps of locales, though I have never seen anything in the literature about it (maybe I should write something about it ?).

A map of locale $f:X \to Y$ can be thought of as a point of $Y$ in the internal logic of the sheaf topos $Sh(X)$. And a sequence/net of such maps $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ can be thought of as an $I$-indexed sequence of points of $Y$ in the internal logic of $Sh(X)$.

**Definition 1:** I say that the sequence/net $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ converge to $f$ if the statement "$(f_i)_{i\in I}$ converge de $f$ as points of $Y$" holds in the internal logic of the topos $Sh(X)$.

If you are fluent in internal/external translation, it is not too hard to write down explicitly what this means:

**Definition 2:** $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ converge to $f$, if for each open $U \in \mathcal{O}(Y)$ there exists a covering $(V_j)$ of $f^*(U)$ and for each $j$ an index $i_j \in I$ such that for all $i > i_j$, $V_j \subset f_i^*(U)$.

And you can use definition 2 as your starting point if you don't like internal logic. Note that definition $2$ can also be written in the more compact, though harder to read way:

**Definition 3:** $(f_i)_{i \in I} \to f$ if for all $U \in \mathcal{O}(Y)$ one has

$$ f^* U \subset \bigcup_{i\in I} \left( \bigcap_{j>i} f_j^*(U) \right) $$

It is easy to see that if $X$ is compact then this is the same as uniform convergence and if $X$ is locally compact then this corresponds to uniform convergence on all compacts.

It seems the analogue notion for topological spaces has been studied under the name **"continuous convergence"**. I had mention this a few years ago in [another MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187193/between-compact-and-locally-uniform-what-is-the-name-of-this-convergence/187474#187474). (I had given a reference in this other answer, but I honestly don't remember it).

There is also another point of view on this notion of convergence which is quite convenient. I'll restrict to $I = \mathbb{N}$ for simplicity. I'm writting $\overline{\mathbb{N}}$ for the topological space $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty \}$ with the topology whose open are all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and all subsets containing $\infty$ and all large enough integer. So a continuous map $f:\overline{\mathbb{N}} \to X$ is the same as a sequence of points $(f(n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ that converge to $f(\infty)$. Then we have:

**Proposition:** A sequence of maps of locale $(f_n:X \to Y)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge to $f :X \to Y$ in the sense above if and only if there exists a map of locale $F: X \times \overline{\mathbb{N}} \to Y$ such that $F$ restricted to $X \times \{n\}$ is $f_n$ and $F$ restricted to $X \times \{\infty\}$ if $f$.

I feel like writting the details of the proof would be a bit too long for an MO answer, but a key point if you are trying to prove it is that one can describe explicitly the locale $X \times \overline{\mathbb{N}}$ : an open is a collection $(U_i)_{i \in \overline{\mathbb{N}}}$ such that:

$$U_\infty \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left( \bigcap_{m >n} U_m \right) $$

In particular, if $X$ is exponentiable, then as a morphism $X \times \overline{\mathbb{N}} \to Y$ is the same as a morphism $\overline{\mathbb{N}} \to Y^X$, one deduces that:

**Corollary:** If $X$ is exponentiable, then a sequence of function $f_n:X \to Y$ converge to $f:X \to Y$ in the sense above if and only if $f_n$ converge to $f$ as points of $Y^X$.